# SpringSecurity + AWS Cognito connection error occurred in SecurityConfig

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, build.gradle, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2

I am practicing AWS cognito linkage with springboot.
However, a mysterious error occurred in securityconfig.
I have no idea why the error occurred.
Is the gradle setting wrong?

here is the code.

SecurityConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

and CognitoWebConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
public class CognitoWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }
}
```

and build.grade file

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.16.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

group = 'jpabook'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'


configurations {
compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}


repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'


implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'


implementation 'com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.5.6'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'


implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.3.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-jose', version: '5.3.4.RELEASE'


testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '2.5'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '4.0.0.RELEASE'


}
```

Lastly, it's an error message. It's a bit long.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:678) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1402) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at jpabook.jpashop.JpashopApplication.main(JpashopApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:678) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1402) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> ... 24 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:678) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1402) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1453) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1231) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> ... 46 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1453) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1231) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> ... 62 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> ... 78 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD
> at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder.build(ClientRegistration.java:523) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.lambda$getClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$86e7f9b3.CGLIB$clientRegistrationRepository$0() ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$86e7f9b3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d8c711b.invoke() ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$86e7f9b3.clientRegistrationRepository() ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
> ... 79 common frames omitted

Somebody Help me..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was dependency. The springboot version in build.gradle was changed to **2.3.4.RELEASE** and activated.